# JavaScript minus zero changes results

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was playing around with Arrays in jsfiddle and noticed that when I do this:

```
let a = [0,1,2,3,4];

for (let i in a) {
    console.log(a.indexOf(i));
}
```

it logs:

[image: -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

But when I do:

```
let a = [0,1,2,3,4];

for (let i in a) {
    console.log(a.indexOf(i - 0));
}
```

it logs:

[image: 0,1,2,3,4]

Minus zero changed the result!

At first I thought it was a jsfiddle problem, but then I tried it with my code editor the same thing happened. Why does this happen can someone explain to me?

Comment: the `for... in` operator is used to iterate over objects. Despite the visual structure of what an array is in JS (with brackets), an `Array` is actually an object with array-like properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
for (let i in a) ...
```

This will iterate over indexes of the array as **strings**. It treats the array like an object and iterates over the indexes like keys. You will get strings: `"0", "1"...`

You can see that if you print the value and type:

```js
let a = [0,1,2,3,4];

for (let i in a) {
    console.log(i, typeof i)
}
```

Those strings are not in your array — your array has numbers — so `findIndex()` doesn't find them and gives you `-1`. However when you subtract 0, javascript converts to an integer for you and suddenly it finds them because the indexes match the values.

What you probably want is `for...of` to iterate  over the values:

```js
let a = [0,1,2,3,4];

for (let i of a) {
    console.log("i:", i, typeof i)
    console.log("index:", a.indexOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that [*indexOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) uses strict equality where `1 !== '1'`.

Answer (score 5):

`For... in` loop is meant to use on objects. In your particular case, the `i` element in the loop is not a value from the array, but it's key.

Key is typeof `string` and since you don't have any strings in your array, you are getting `-1` with every cycle.

Using `- 0` **evaluates the string into a number**.

**Note**: It's an unique and "happy" situation, since your elements in the array are sorted, iterated integers starting at 0. That's why it seems to work properly.

Just a quick showcase:

```js
const keys = Object.assign({}, [0, 1, 2, 3]);

console.log(keys);
console.log(typeof Object.keys(keys)[0]);
```

Snippet above represents how your array is interpreted by `for... in` loop. As you can easily see, every key from such object is a `string`.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look:
let a = [0,1,2,3,4];

```
for (let i in a) {
    console.log(a.indexOf(a[i]));
}
```